# Getting a list of changed and not yet flushed objects in a "before commit" hook

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, zope, zodb

Context: Pyramid, SQLAlchemy session with ZopeTransactionExtension, Pyramid transaction manager.

This doc (http://zodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/transactions.html#more-features-and-things-to-keep-in-mind-about-transactions ) says:

*Before-commit hooks*

*In some cases, it may be desirable to execute some code right before a transaction is committed. For example, if an operation needs to be performed on all objects changed during a transaction, it might be better to call it once at commit time instead of every time an object is changed, which could slow things down.*

I need to do exactly that (get a list of changed objects, whether flushed or not), but the problem is hook functions that can be added by `current_transaction.addBeforeCommitHook()` appear to receive only args and kwargs passed by the programmers: not a list of changed objects, not a transaction, etc.

Q: How to get hook access objects *changed in current transaction before they are flushed*?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the solution, although not in "before commit" hook, but rather by inheriting from `ZopeTransactionExtension`:

```
class ZopeTransactionExtensionWithRequest(ZopeTransactionExtension):

    def before_flush(self, session, flush_context, instances):
        super(ZopeTransactionExtensionWithRequest, self).before_flush(session, flush_context, instances)
        for sqa_inst in session.dirty:
            pass
```

Comment: Right, because the objects that have been changed is very specific to the transaction extension, but the hook isn't; it only knows about the transaction. You'd ask the transaction for all extensions and find the ones with a SQLAlchemy session, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can access session.dirty with [get_current_request](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/threadlocal.html#pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_request)